# For $a, b \in \mathbb Z,\;$ if $\;a^2(b^2-2b)$ is odd, then a and b are odd. Proof check.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Suppose $a,b$ are integers, if $a^2(b^2-2b)$ is odd, then a and b are odd, is my solution the best way?
PS: I know this is easy but **do i need to expand the final answer?** because im practicing for exams and time is of the essence and i want it to be direct as possible.
**P -> Q right? now contraposition Q' -> 'P. negation of (a is odd and b is odd) is a is even or b is even so its correct to assume both is even since it still gives a boolean value of True** I dont get why my first solution was wrong :(
Method of proof: Contraposition
$$ a = 2k $$
$$ b = 2j $$
$$ a^2(b^2-2b) = 4k^2(4j^2 - 4j) $$
$$ 2[k^2(4j^2-4j)]$$ by definition it is even

EDIT: why is my answer wrong? ive made a and b even which is 'Q, then ive proved Q' -> P'

EDIT #2: is this correct now?
Method of proof: Contraposition
$$ a = 2k $$
$$ b = 2j + 1 $$
$$ a^2(b^2-2b) = 4k^2((2j+1)^2 - 4j+2) $$
$$ 2[k^2((2j+1)^2 - 4j+2)]$$ by definition it is even (this is the most efficient solution? for time limits in tests?)

EDIT #3: Hope this is final
Method of proof: Contraposition
$$ a = 2k $$
$$ b = 2j + 1 $$
$$ a^2(b^2-2b) = 4k^2((2j+1)^2 - 4j+2) $$
$$ 2[k^2((2j+1)^2 - 4j+2)]$$ by definition it is even when a is even

and

$$ a = 2k+1 $$
$$ b = 2j $$
$$ a^2(b^2-2b) = (2k+1)^2(4j^2 - 4j) $$
$$ 2[((2k+1)^2(2j^2 - 2j)]$$ by definition it is even when b is even

is this an efficient way now? also i still dont get why i have to prove 'A V 'B biconditionally.

Comment: You don't have the correct starting assumption to prove the contrapositive; if you assume the statement "$a$ and $b$ are odd" is false, then you're assuming that $a$ is even *or* $b$ is even, not both.

Comment: wait i dont understand P -> Q right? but i've proven  Q' -> P' so why is my answer wrong?

Comment: The problem states that both $a$ and $b$ are odd. The complementary event is that **at least** one is even. so $Q'$ is not correct as you have stated it.

Comment: You *haven't* proven $Q'\implies P'$ - the statement $Q'$ is "$a$ is even or $b$ is even", *not* "$a$ and $b$ are both even".

Comment: Negation to the statement "$a$ and $b$ are odd" is "at least one of $a$ or $b$ is even".

Comment: but a = even ^ b = even equates to true as well as a = even V b = odd

Comment: @MattPressland edited is it correct now?

Comment: Still needs more - to do it this way, you need the two proofs you've already done, and the missing one where $a$ is odd and $b$ is even; I think Hagen's method will be faster. Do you understand why the opposite of the statement "$a$ and $b$ are odd" is not "$a$ and $b$ are even"?

Comment: Do you know DeMorgan's Law? It states that: $$\neg (p \land q) \iff \neg p \lor \neg q$$

Comment: I need to prove both?????? wait lemme try

Comment: Actually, as an amendment to my last comment, the *quickest* way (using contrapositive) will be to prove it assuming $a$ is even and assuming nothing about $b$, and to prove it assuming $b$ is even and assuming nothing about $a$ - this cuts down the number of cases by one. As various commenters have pointed out, you should start from the assumption that at least one of $a$ or $b$ is even, and the proof will be slightly different depending on which one you assume is even.

Comment: @MattPressland thats what I did in the first proof! :)) but you said it was wrong

Comment: Hint:  Factor $a^2(b^2 - b)$, and assume that either $a$ or $b$ (or both) are even.  What happens?

Comment: @vincentbelkin No, it isn't - in the first proof you assumed both $a$ and $b$ were even at the same time; I'm saying you have to prove it assuming one is even, and then prove it assuming the other is even.

Comment: @JavaMan so i can assume their both even right!!! thats what i dont understand. why their saying i cant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've now managed to get to a complete proof, I'll write up a slightly slicker version for you (I won't do all the algebraic manipulation, but you should be able to fill that in yourself).

As pointed out by several people, if we're going to use the contrapositive, we start by assuming that $a$ and $b$ are not both even, or equivalently, that at least one is odd.

So first we assume that $a=2k$ is even. Then:

$$a^2(b^2-2b)=4k^2(b^2-2b)$$

is even as required. (Note that I have made *no* assumption about $b$ here.)

Then we assume that $b=2j$ is even. Then:

$$a^2(b^2-2b)=4a^2(j^2-j)$$

is even as required. (This time I make no assumptions on $a$).

Comment: thats the complete proof? but can i just do one? the a is even? no need to prove the b is even part? cause its time consuming or is is essential to the proof

Comment: Think of it this way - if you only do the first part, you don't know what happens if, say, $a=5$ and $b=4$. As these numbers satisfy the assumption "$a$ and $b$ are not both odd", you do need to prove that in this case $a^2(b^2-2b)$ is not odd.

Comment: @vincentbelkin: Matt has shown that if either $a$ or $b$ are even, then $a^2(b^2-2b)$ is even. The contrapositive o that statement is: if $a^2(b^2-2b)$ is odd, then both $a$ and $b$ are odd.

Comment: AWESOME!!!! I get it now!!!!! thanks man

Comment: @robjohn Thanks for catching the typo. :)

Answer (score 4):

You show: If *both* numbers $a$ and $b$ are even, then the expression is even. This is not what is asked for.

I suggest to rather use that a product is odd iff all factors are odd.

Comment: yeah which is proof by contraposition??? is there an easier way? but my answer is correct right?

Answer (score 4):

You have assumed that $a$ and $b$ are *both* even, and showed that if so, $a^2(b^2-b)$ is also even.  By contraposition, this shows that if $a^2(b^2-b)$ is not even, then it is not true that $a$ and $b$ are both even.  That is, you have shown only that at least one of *a* and *b* is not, not that both of them are odd.

Contraposition will still work, but you need to show that if $a$ is even then $a^2(b^2-b)$ is even, and also that if $b$ is even $a^2(b^2-b)$ is even.

---

I'm going to try to explain your mistake another way.

You want to show:

$$a^2(b^2-b)\text{ is odd}\implies (a\text{ is odd}\wedge b\text{ is odd})$$

You are trying to do this by controposition, which means you want to prove the contrapositive:

$$\lnot\left\{a\text{ is odd}\wedge b\text{ is odd}\right\}\implies \lnot \left\{a^2(b^2-b)\text{ is odd}\right\}.$$

So you need to start by assuming $$\lnot\left\{a\text{ is odd}\wedge b\text{ is odd}\right\}$$

but instead, you started by assuming $$\lnot a\text{ is odd}\land \lnot b\text{ is odd}$$

and then when you tried to correct your proof you started by assuming $$\lnot a\text{ is odd}\land b\text{ is odd}.$$

Neither of these is going to so what you want.

Comment: isn't that for biconditional expressions only?

Comment: edited is it correct now?

Comment: No; it now shows only that if $a^2(b^2-b)$ is odd then $a$ is odd. You have not showed that $b$ must also be odd.

Comment: i started by assuming a is even and b is even..

Comment: You're right, but it still won't work.  I have corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\ a^2b^2\! - 2a^2b = 1\!+\!2n\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{a^2b^2}= 1\!+\! 2(n\!+\!a^2b),\,$ so $\,\color{#c00}a\,$ or $\,\color{#c00}b\,$ even $\rm\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{even} = odd.$

The same idea shows $\ a_1\cdots a_n\! + 2k = 1\! +\! 2n\ $ then all $\,a_i\,$ are odd. So a product of integers is odd iff each factor is odd. This is a special case of the fact that a product is invertible iff each factor is invertible (this fundamental fact is true in any ring).

Answer (score 0):

We already have some nifty proofs, however since this is a parity problem, it seems reasonable to prove it using ${\bf parity-operators}$. so let's do just that.

The problem can be rewritten, by contrapositive, as: the expression is even provided $a$ or $b$ is even. So let's prove just that.
[We goto contrapositive since I prefer working with $\mathsf{even}$ instead of $\mathsf{odd}$.]

$
\hspace{0.5cm}\mathsf{even}(a^2(b^2-2b)) 
\\\equiv \mathsf{even}(a^2b^2-2ab) \hspace{4.3cm}\text{Using arithmetic}
\\\equiv \mathsf{even}(ab)^2 \equiv \mathsf{even}(-2a^2b)
    \hspace{3cm}\text{Using property: $\mathsf{even}(n+m) \equiv \mathsf{even}(n) \equiv \mathsf{even}(m)$}
\\\equiv \mathsf{even}(ab)^2 \equiv \mathsf{true}
   \hspace{4.2cm}\text{ Multiples of 2 are even}
\\\equiv \mathsf{even}(ab)^2 \hspace{5.2cm}\text{`True' is identity of `$\equiv$'}
\\\Leftarrow \mathsf{even}(ab) \hspace{5.2cm}\text{Using property: $\mathsf{even}(n^2) \Leftarrow \mathsf{even}(n)$}
\\\Leftarrow \mathsf{even}(a) \text{ or } \mathsf{even}(b)
\hspace{4cm}\text{Using property: $\mathsf{even}(nm) \Leftarrow \mathsf{even}(n) \text{ or } \mathsf{even}(m)$}
$

Best regards,

Moses